# How to define a default Action for any http method in Play 2.1 (Scala)?

Tags: http, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm writing RESTful web services using the Play framework (Scala variant), version 2.1.1.

For a given resource, I want to be able to process POST requests, but for any other method I want to return a MethodNotAllowed response.

My routes-file attempt (snippet):

```
# Item-related actions
POST    /item   controllers.ItemController.newItem
GET     /item   controllers.ApplicationController.methodNotAllowed
PUT     /item   controllers.ApplicationController.methodNotAllowed
DELETE  /item   controllers.ApplicationController.methodNotAllowed
HEAD    /item   controllers.ApplicationController.methodNotAllowed
OPTIONS /item   controllers.ApplicationController.methodNotAllowed
PATCH   /item   controllers.ApplicationController.methodNotAllowed
```

But I get a warning in the Play console:

```
[warn] /home/bruno/Entwicklung/pServer/conf/routes:8: unreachable code
[warn] PUT    /itemcontrollers.ApplicationController.methodNotAllowed
```

How come several, distinct routes can render some “unreachable code”? I understand the reverse-resolution mechanism should be given a clear set of rules in order to operate without ambiguities, but the direct mechanism, which is what I’m interested in right now, should be working out-of-the-box. Or not?

Since this case, from my point of view, must be rather common when programming REST services, I’m sure I’m missing something important here.

Should you have any suggestion as to the best way to approach this problem, I’ll appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to figure out all possible bad access points to generate error messages. Instead, you can override the `onHandlerNotFound` method in the application's `Global` object.

Adapted from Play's official documentation: [ScalaGlobal](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaGlobal)

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results.__

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader): Result = {
    // implement methodNotAllowed controller Action
  }  
}
```

Comment: In Play 2.1 there is no longer an `onActionNotFound()` method, but there is an `onHandlerNotFound()`, which is good enough, I believe. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: But then again… is there an easy way to find out whether a handler was not found because of a missing route, or because of a missing verb?

I mean: I'm writing web services, so if I receive (as a matter of example) a request for a resource that simply does not exist, I want to return a 404 (default behaviour). On the other hand, if I receive via POST a request that would have been served if the GET method had been used instead, I want to return a `MethodNotAllowed` response.

Comment: I don't think there is an *easy* way of doing this, but in the mean time, I don't think it is a good idea.  

In my opinion, a bad HTTP verb should not be looked at differently than a bad HTTP url; After all, you could do everything with only a GET verb and add the verb as a suffix to the url, they serve the same purpose: map to a controller method. But then, you might have a good reason to want to do this?

Comment: Well… what I'm trying to achieve is a set of RESTful web services, for which I have defined a number of resources and in which the meaning of the HTTP verbs is taken in a very RESTful manner (or so I try)  :)

As an example, let me show you in next comment a snippet of my routes file:

Comment: `# Item-related actions
    POST     /item       controllers.ItemController.newItem

    GET      /item/:id   controllers.ItemController.get(id: Long)
    PUT      /item/:id   controllers.ItemController.modify(id: Long)
    DELETE   /item/:id   controllers.ItemController.delete(id: Long)
    GET      /items      controllers.ItemController.find(latitude: Long, longitude: Long, scope: Int ?= 10000, text ?= "", offset: Int ?= 0, n: Int ?= 20)`

Comment: Gosh, format is not helping me here. But anyway…

As you can see, I have the same resource several times (`/item/:id`), and I even have another, very similar one (`/item`). The only difference between them is the HTTP verb, as is expected in RESTful WS (or so I believe).

Thus, I would like the client to get a 404 when it asks (via GET) for, let's say, `/idontexist/45`, or `/item/99999999` (assuming item 99999999 doesn't exist), but a 405 when it tries to POST a request to `/item/1` (whether item 1 exists or not).

I hope I'm being clear, and I understand my understanding of HTTP might be poor

Comment: I do understand what you are trying to do but I still think that you are over-complicating things. If you want to handle certain routes that you do not support in a particular way, you **will** have to define them. When designing a recent api, I found this link very helpful when it came to error handling: https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_what_about_errors

Comment: I agree, that article is very clear and very concise. Thank you for the reference. I'm not trying to return a big subset of the HTTP status codes, but I feel the need to help the clients discriminate whether the path is wrong (404) or the method is wrong (405).

I see what you mean when you write "_you **will** have to define them_". But *that's exactly* what I was trying to do in the first place! What I was trying to do when I stumbled into this problem was being explicit as to which routes, although existing, did not accept those methods.  :-D